# How to animate an ImageView inside a RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have an image view aligned in the centre of a relative layout. What I want is when a button is pressed, is to animate it from the it's current position to align to the top of the parent layout.

What is the best approach to achieve this? Is it possible to define this animation in xml?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

iv.animate().translationY(-iv.getTop()).setDuration(1000); // 1000 ms
```

Will animate the `ImageView` to the top inside its container layout. (in your case, the `RelativeLayout`)

`View.animate().translationY(int to)` will animate **to** a specific value.